# How do teams deal with a death of a colleague

Tags: software-industry, death

How to teams in large organizations deal with the death of a colleague? Are they supposed to go about their week like normal or is there a period of time given to grieve?

Comment: The fact that you mentioned "in large organizations" leads to the question of the relationships you're interested in. Responses will be different if it's the team the colleague was on, a team that worked closely with the person, etc. If the person was a founder, upper management, mid-level, team lead...Location may matter too as cultural norms can affect responses.

Answer (score 6):

A lot depends on the circumstances. Special councelling may be needed for some if the colleague died on the job, even more if it was a messy accident at work. In my experience some people will just filter themselves out of the job altogether if it was too traumatic for them. Probably a rare occassion in software development I would think.

If the colleague died elsewhere then people are expected to deal with it in the usual social ways of their culture. In some this includes collecting some money for the family, or attending the funeral, but each culture would have different ways of handling it.

Answer (score 4):

The team is expected to work normally. The *individuals* in the team who were particularly close to the deceased may be given some slack while they recover. Talk to your manager if you think you are one of the few who need that special consideration... or just take some vacation time.